# How to embed another language in a custom language using TokensProvider

Tags: monaco-editor

`MonarchTokensProvider` supports embedding other languages by using the `nextEmbedded` attribute. This makes it possible to nest javascript and css inside html for example.

Can the same be accomplished using the manual implementation `TokensProvider`?

Comment: any answer for this?